# Firebase remote config does not return values

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

I'm using Firebase Remote Config in my application and I need to get data, but I get nothing instead.

My DI:

```kotlin
    single {
        Firebase.remoteConfig.apply {
            setConfigSettingsAsync(
                FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                    .setFetchTimeoutInSeconds(86400) // 24h
                    .build()
            )
        }
    }
```

My method:

```kotlin
    fun getBot() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val tokenResult = runCatching {
                remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().await()
            }
            val token = runCatching { remoteConfig.getString("settings") }
            Log.e("TAG", "getBot: ${tokenResult}")
            Log.e("TAG", "getBot: ${token}")
            if (tokenResult.isSuccess && token.getOrNull().orEmpty().isNotEmpty()) {
                // todo
            } else {
                // todo
            }
        }
    }
```

Console log:

```kotlin
getBot: Success(false)
getBot: Success()
```

I have same package name, google-servies.json and keys
Everything is working fine on one phone, but not on the other